# Zero is greater than empty string in VBA but not in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm aware that Excel treats text values as higher than any number. When I ask Excel whether a cell containing 0 is greater than a cell containing "", it (as expected) tells me FALSE. Similarly, if I ask Excel whether a cell containing 0 is greater than "", it also tells me FALSE:

[image]

However, when I make these same comparisons in VBA I get different answers:

[image]

Strangely, if I reverse the direction of the inequality in that second line, I still get TRUE:

[image]

I'll also note that VBA returns a type mismatch error when I directly try to compare 0 with "":

```
Debug.Print 0 > ""
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges...

Comment: Excel formulae and VBA are different programming languages. Their designers made different choices about how to interpret odd cases like the ones you mention. There's no reason to expect the formula and VBA results to be the same.

Comment: The last screenshot shows VBA returns TRUE regardless of the direction of the inequality. I would not expect any programming language to have that behavior, so why does VBA behave that way?

Comment: You swapped the left- and right-hand sides as well... `a > b` and `b < a` are equivalent.

Comment: Stupid mistake... Thanks